# Is there a way to display custom product on home page with add to cart button and description for WooCommerce?

Tags: css, function

I'm trying to find a way to display specific product on homepage with add to cart button and description as shown in the picture below. Thanks in advance.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgIxB.png)

Comment: please provide some code. you're only using css?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.